# ApiClaims, IdentityClaims, RoleClaims with IdentityServer4 version 2.1.0

Tags: identityserver4

I see these tables in the identity database, how are these claims set at the code level and what are they for?

- ApiClaims
- IdentityClaims
- RoleClaims

Answer (score 1):

**ApiClaims** are the claims that Identity Server 4 include in the access token when a client ask for authorization to a scope using OAuth.

**IdentityClaims** are the claims included in the identity token when a client ask for authentication using OpenID Connect.

This two tables are part of IdentityServer4 Entity Framerwork storage.

Instead **RoleClaims** is part of the ASP.Net Identity storage used by Identity Server 4. I've never used it.